# Serialize array of unknown Type with Protobuf .Net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm having some embarass trying to serialize this data structure:

```cs
protected string EngineQualifiedName
{
    get { return Engine == null ? null : Engine.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
    set { Engine = value == null? null : Type.GetType(value); }
}

public Type Engine { get; protected set; }

public string Method { get; protected set; }

public Type[] ParameterTypes { get; protected set; }
```

The problem is, obviously, related with the serialization of ParameterTypes. Reading about other similar issues here in stack overflow, I've written a formatter like this one:

```
public static IFormatter Formatter(IEnumerable<Type> paramTypes)
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ProtoBufRequest), true).Add(1, "ParameterCompositeValues").Add(2, "EngineQualifiedName").Add(3, "Method");
    var ct = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(CompositeType), true);         
    var ctType = typeof (CompositeType<>);

    var j = 0;
    foreach (var paramType in paramTypes)
    {
        try
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(paramType, true);
        }
        catch
        { }

        ct.AddSubType(j + 4, ctType.MakeGenericType(paramType));

        j++;
    }

    return RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CreateFormatter(typeof (ProtoBufRequest));
}
```

And I've used those properties and class to mask the array of Type:

```
private CompositeType[] ParameterCompositeValues
{
    get
    {
        if (ParameterValues == null)
            return null;

        var create = typeof (CompositeType).GetMethod("Create");
        return
            ParameterValues.Select(
                    (t, i) => (CompositeType) create.MakeGenericMethod(ParameterTypes[i]).Invoke(null, new[] {t})).ToArray();
    }
    set
    {
        ParameterValues = value == null ? null : value.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray();
    }
}

[ProtoContract(UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
internal abstract class CompositeType
{
    protected abstract object ValueImpl { get; set; }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return ValueImpl; }
        set { ValueImpl = value; }
    }


    public static CompositeType<T> Create<T>(T value)
    {
        return new CompositeType<T> {Value = value};
    }
}


[ProtoContract(UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
internal class CompositeType<T> : CompositeType
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public new T Value { get; set; }

    protected override object ValueImpl
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T) value; }
    }
}
```

My problem actually is, when I try to serialize classes of generics (for example, a Speaker, where T is not known), the formatter faces some problems, and in deserialization I obtain an empty class, with all its values to null. Am I doing something wrong? 
The generic classes are serialized in the correct way, but if I try to set them up in this way, this system of messages isn't able to serialize and deserialize correctly :\

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Re `ParameterTypes`, `System.Type` has direct handling in the current trunk (but not in the released dll) - so you don't need any additional formatting (it uses the pre-existing `Type` serialization that can be optionally hooked via the model event).

I should emphasize; that any dynamic subclass handling is very dependent on the keys entered. What you describe is not the "classic" use-case scenario for the tool. It can probably be forced to work, but! You'd also need to watch for duplicates, and changing the default model while it is in use could cause it to say "no".

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what the problem scenario is here - i.e. what the specific question is; can you clarify?

Comment: Sounds like a question for @MarcGravell (user:23354) he is an expert in proto bufs

Comment: @MarcGravell Haha ! You showed up before I could even type your name !!! :-P

Comment: @MarcGravell: So you are actually suggesting me to try and see if the code in the svn works for my needings? I'm implementing a Messaging Service to send serialized data in Azure, and ProtoBuf .Net is the best serializing solution to make it working both in Windows and Mono :) The actual example works well with DataContractSerializer (with some expedients).

Comment: @VollmonD no, I'm saying "please help me understand where specifically it fails, so I can give the best possible guidance". I don't want to lead you astray by my misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @Mika a bit like Beeteljuice :p

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok! Well, I've made a fast example of class hierarchy that doesn't work with my formatter. Basically when I try to add a Speaker<MyClass> in the way I modelled my serializer, the formatter isn't able to find out the values of MyClass, and it returns an empty istance. The code of hierarchy and engine is  reachable here: http://pastebin.com/eAK4wDUb

Comment: @VollmonD ah, right; I missed your comment - will investigate later

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you, don't worry!

Comment: @MarkGravell I had some time to play and I've tried the r485 (I was using the packaged one, the r480) of your library. It looks like it is working with my array of Type without creating a personal formatter reflection. If you suggest me to try the code from SVN in a reply, I'll mark it as resolved :)